# How to sort an array in PHP maintaining the order but changing which comes first based on a value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This questions was difficult to word but I'll explain myself. I have an array of days of the week and an according image that will eventually be echoed out to the browser in an unordered list.

```
    array(7) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["offer_day"]=>
        string(6) "Monday"
        ["offer_img"]=>
        string() "/imgpath.jpg"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["offer_day"]=>
        string(7) "Tuesday"
        ["offer_img"]=>
        string(11) "/imgpath.jpg"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["offer_day"]=>
        string(9) "Wednesday"
        ["offer_img"]=>
        string(11) "/imgpath.jpg"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        ["offer_day"]=>
        string(8) "Thursday"
        ["offer_img"]=>
        string(11) "/imgpath.jpg"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(2) {
        ["offer_day"]=>
        string(6) "Friday"
        ["offer_img"]=>
        string(11) "/imgpath.jpg"
      }
      [5]=>
      array(2) {
        ["offer_day"]=>
        string(8) "Saturday"
        ["offer_img"]=>
        string(11) "/imgpath.jpg"
      }
      [6]=>
      array(2) {
        ["offer_day"]=>
        string(6) "Sunday"
        ["offer_img"]=>
        string(11) "/imgpath.jpg"
      }
    }
```

I want the array to be sorted according to what day it is. So if it's Wednesday I want the echoed out array to look something like this:

```
    <ul>
      <li>Wednesday<img src="/imgpath.jpg" alt="image"></li>
      <li>Thursday<img src="/imgpath.jpg" alt="image"></li>
      <li>Friday<img src="/imgpath.jpg" alt="image"></li>
      <li>Saturday<img src="/imgpath.jpg" alt="image"></li>
      <li>Sunday<img src="/imgpath.jpg" alt="image"></li>
      <li>Monday<img src="/imgpath.jpg" alt="image"></li>
      <li>Tuesday<img src="/imgpath.jpg" alt="image"></li>
    </ul>
```

How do I reorder an array based on a certain value e.g. `$day = date("l");` but maintain the general order. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't "sort", slice:

```
$reordered = array_merge(array_slice($array, $offset), array_slice($array, 0, $offset));
```

Determine `$offset` based on `date('N')`.